# Как спрятаться от ВК

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет. ВКонтакте положил мой сайт в черный список. Теперь при клики по ссылки он блокирует переход на мой сайт.

Имею другой сайт, хочу с него делать редирект на свой основной. Только Вот как от вк спрятаться. Я так понимаю нужно скрывать http_referer по нему ВК определяет куда попадет человек. Какие идеи есть, помогите.

Comment: Не творить Зло? Техподдержка Вам в помощь.

Comment: @Other нее в ВК не позволит мне использовать мой сайт. Он вредит им )

Comment: Вы - Марк? Тогда, да. Но всё же - в чём причина блокировки?

Comment: В распространение рекламы на мой сайт, люди много ссылок на мой сайт дают а ВК начал делать из за этого блокировку. Хочет чтобы я В него рекламу заказывал а я ее распространяю сам.

Comment: При чем тут вообще http_referer ?

Answer (score 4):

Для вставки ссылки на заблокированный ресурс используйте данную схему перехода с проверкой на роботов (надежнее всего [Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/comingsoon/invisiblebeta.html))

1. Ссылка на сайт A, который не забанен в ВК  `http://site1.com?mySuperURL=/video/153`, где **mySuperURL** это место на сайте B, куда нужно отправить пользователя *(обрати внимание что адрес без домена)*
2. На сайте А делаем проверку на робота

[image: Google reCAPTCHA]

3. При успешной проверке записыаем пользователю в куки что он наш довереный человек и делаем редирект на **mySuperURL**. При последующих заходах смотрим если наш секретный кук у него есть - то пускаем на нужный ресурс без проверки на робота
4. При попытке перехода на сайт B (может быть и прямым) проверяем есть ли кук, если нет, то кидаем на страницу проверки на робота, либо белая страница.

Для генерации ссылок лучше всего сделать какую-то утилитарную страницу, и периодически менять правила составления ссылок, домены и ip-адреса ([про динамические ip-адреса](https://habrahabr.ru/post/101336/)).

Думаю что если сайт блокируется администрацией ВК, значит там есть что-то такое, ради чего пользователям не составит труда пройти проверку от роботов. Делать прямой редирект не имеет смысла, так как робот ВК также пройдет редирект.